# Listbox dinâmica com faixa de valores

Tags: c#, asp.net

O meu problema consiste em conseguir tratar de uma maneira adequada o meu `listbox` em que estou fazendo uma "faixa de valores" em meu sistema.

Preciso que ele não deixe por codebehind adicionar um valor que esteja contido na faixa de valores.. Ex: 0-10 foi adicionado, agora não posso deixar ele adicionar 9-20 pois o 9 é contido na faixa 0-10..

Como posso proceder? Segue em anexo as imagens do sistema e suas linhas de código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
protected void btnAdicionarGastos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (Tratar.Int(txtGastosDe.Value) <= Tratar.Int(txtGastosAte.Value))
                    {
                        string gasto = txtGastosDe.Value + " - " + txtGastosAte.Value;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gasto))
                        {
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable("dxlstGastos");
                            if (lstGastos.Visible == false)
                            {
                                lstGastos.Visible = true;
                                btnRemoverGastos.Visible = true;
                            }
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtGastosDe.Value) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtGastosAte.Value))
                            {
                                if (!lstGastos.Items.Contains(lstGastos.Items.FindByText(gasto)))
                                {
                                    dt.Columns.Add("GASTOS");
                                    foreach (ListItem item in lstGastos.Items)
                                    {
                                        DataRow dr;
                                        dr = dt.NewRow();
                                        dr["GASTOS"] = item.Value;
                                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                                    }
                                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                                    row.BeginEdit();
                                    row["GASTOS"] = gasto;
                                    row.EndEdit();
                                    dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
                                    dt.AcceptChanges();

                                    lstGastos.DataSource = dt;
                                    lstGastos.DataTextField = "GASTOS";
                                    lstGastos.DataBind();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Alerta("Não insira valores em branco.");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Alerta("Por favor, insira valores finais maiores que os iniciais.");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Você não editou nada, não é mesmo Ricardo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondi da seguinte maneira:

```
protected void btnAdicionarGastos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Tratar.Int(txtGastosDe.Value) <= Tratar.Int(txtGastosAte.Value))
            {
                string gasto = txtGastosDe.Value + " - " + txtGastosAte.Value;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gasto))
                {
                    foreach (ListItem item in lstGastos.Items)
                    {
                        string[] itm = Tratar.String(item.Value.Replace("-", ",")).Split(new char[] { ',' });
                        int valorinicial = Tratar.Int(itm[0], 0);
                        int valorfinal = Tratar.Int(itm[1], 0);
                        int gastode = Tratar.Int(txtGastosDe.Value, 0);
                        int gastoate = Tratar.Int(txtGastosAte.Value, 0);
                        if ((gastode <= valorinicial && gastoate >= valorfinal) || (gastoate >= valorinicial && gastoate <= valorfinal))
                        {
                            Alerta("Valores foram encontrados no intervalo entre as faixas");
                            return;
                        }
                        else if ((gastode >= valorinicial && gastode <= valorfinal) || (gastoate >= valorinicial && gastoate <= valorfinal))
                        {
                            Alerta("Valores foram encontrados no intervalo entre as faixas");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    lstGastos.Items.Add(gasto);
                }
                else
                {
                    Alerta("Não insira valores em branco.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Alerta("Por favor, insira valores finais maiores que os iniciais.");
            }

        }
```